# Set up XPage Extension Library Dev environment

Tags: eclipse, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to set up an environment in order to "play around with" developing my own tools for XPages and adding to the extension libraries.  I have been using [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dchOyzjy9L4) as a basis for setting up the environment.  As a few people in the comments have pointed out, it is no longer possible to get the "IBM Development Package for Eclipse" skd50 version; only the ..70 version is available.  Since I was trying to add to a later version of the ExtLibs, I decided to give it a try anyway.  After importing the ExtLib projects, I had thousands of compile errors due to not having the correct sdk.  I have also not found any hint of something that could help on openNTF.org.

Is anyone aware of a way to edit/add to the ExtLib, or know of a source where I can learn the new(?) way of setting up the environment?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an easier way to do it. Just modify the Eclipse configuration to point to Domino. All the details are here -> http://www.intec.co.uk/configuring-eclipse-for-domino-debug-plugin/

Comment: unfortunately, this does not seem to be working out for me.  I posted a comment on the site to ask for further assistance.

Comment: The ini variable points to a local Domino server install and needs to go before vmargs. It can't have any spaces in it, but you can check the filepath works by pasting it into Windows Explorer. For me it was "-vm c:\progra~1\IBM\domino\jvm\bin\javaw.exe"

Comment: Just a quick update: I have tried numerous things using the information in the website you provided.  Again thank you.  I have as of yet been unable to reduce the build errors to below 20000+.  As soon as I can in the next few days, I will update this question to include what I have tried and an example list of build errors that I am getting.  Maybe I am missing a step.

Comment: Are your installed JRE (Java\Installed JREs) and Target Platform (Plugin Development\Target Platform) set to Domino? The target platform sometimes goes a bit screwy in Eclipse, and I have to change it, apply it, change it back and apply it again.

Comment: Plug-In Development / Target was incorrectly set.  After setting that to domino, i now only have 384 errors located in three projects that I most likely do not need to update, "com.ibm.xsp.extlib.test", "com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.test", and "com.ibm.xsp.test.framework".

Comment: Correct, you probably don't need those. I have them as well, looks like they're related to needing Notes Client plugins and junit.

Answer (score 2):

I've been doing the same this week. Good resources are:

1. [Configuring Eclipse for XPages OSGI Plugins - Part 1](http://developmentblog.johnmcooper.co.uk/2014/05/configuring-eclipse-for-xpages-osgi-plugins-part1.html)  as a concise guide for eclipse/xpages sdk/domino debug plugin setup
2. Paul's tip as per above http://www.intec.co.uk/configuring-eclipse-for-domino-debug-plugin/
3. For errors about tests you need to:

   1. Right click on the projects with that error e.g. com.ibm.xsp.extlib.text
   2. Build Path>Add Libraries
   3. JUnit> JUnit3

That got everything to compile for me bar the com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.oauth, which i think may be caused by that needing a plugin only available in the Domino (Server) Target

NB: My Domino install was a default windows one i.e in C:\Program Files.  To let the Domino debug plugin write into that folder I had to run Eclipse as Administrator